# month and year pickers in one page. angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my page I want to have two dropdowns. One is Yearonly picker dropdown and the other is MonthYear picker dropdown.

I have two separate plunkers which works fine for Monthyear picker and Year picker. They are as follows :

Month year picker : [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/itHjnEzYHuOfKTgwUYw2?p=preview)

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    startingDay: 1,
    minMode: 'month'
  };

  $scope.formats = ['MM/yyyy'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
```

Year picker : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0SPMYQ6ND7AOfZwDAFB8?p=preview)

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    startingDay: 1,
    minMode: 'year'
  };

  $scope.formats = ['yyyy'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
```

The problem I am facing is to have both on the same page.

Pickers on same page : [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/33ZuGJ1ZYA90ovaNwdxK?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the two pickers to be able to hold different dates at the same time (not change the other when one of them is changed). To do this, you will need to assign the two inputs different models (ng-model="dt" and ng-model="dtYr").

Also, the function you are calling for the second button is openYR. You have no such function defined in your script (you do have openYr defined though). This is why nothing happens when you click the second button.

The open and openYr functions (responsible for opening that selection menu) change the same variable which is assigned to both 'is-open' attributes. Because it is assigned to both 'is-open' attributes, you see both selection menus open when you click the first button. You thus need openYr to change a different variable that will then be assigned to the year-picker 'is-open'.

Here is the working version: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/09sIgaTLZhsOUwj6arQV?p=preview)

**script.js**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl',
function ($scope) {
  $scope.today function() {
      $scope.dt new Date();
      //CHANGE
      $scope.dtYr new Date();
      //CHANGEEND
  };
  $scope.today();
  $scope.clear function () {
      $scope.dt null;
  };
  $scope.open function($event) {
      $scope.status.opened true;
  };
  //CHANGE
  $scope.openYr function($event) {
      $scope.status.openedYr true;
  };
  //CHANGEEND
  $scope.dateOptions {
      formatYear: 'yyyy', startingDay: 1, minMode: 'month'
  };
  $scope.dateOptionsYr {
      formatYear: 'yyyy', startingDay: 1, minMode: 'year'
  };
  $scope.formats ['MM/yyyy'];
  $scope.format $scope.formats[0];
  $scope.formatsYr ['yyyy'];
  $scope.formatYr $scope.formatsYr[0];
  $scope.status {
      opened: false, //CHANGE
      openedYr: false //CHANGEEND
  };
}
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        .full button span {
            background-color: limegreen;
            border-radius: 32px;
            color: black;
        }
        .partially button span {
            background-color: orange;
            border-radius: 32px;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{formatYr}}" ng-model="dtYr" is-open="status.openedYr" datepicker-options="dateOptionsYr" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openYr($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank u very much.  one more thing I was trying disable certain months in this dropdowns.   I added  >  var monthsToDisable = [4,5,9];         $scope.disableMonth = function (date) {
    var day = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }
    return [true];
}   in the js file  and in html page ng-click="open($event);disableMonth(date)"      but the disable not working. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: That function returns an array of 1 boolean... If you put it in ng-click, I wouldn't expect it to do anything useful (it will get called after you click that button and return the array - in essence doing nothing of value as far as I understand it). Maybe play around some more with the plunker code for 'Datepicker Popup' [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). You have an example of how to use dateDisabled there.